# cannot ping linked docker container service

Tags: docker-compose

having simple setup like this:

```
db:
  image: mysql
web:
  build: .
  command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
  volumes:
    - .:/myapp
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  links:
    - db:db
  environment:
    RAILS_ENV: development
```

if i run:

```
docker-compose build && docker-compose run web ping db
```

i get:

```
Starting myapp_db_1
ping: unknown host
```

why?
if i run:

```
docker-compose run cat /etc/hosts
```

i see this:

```
Starting myapp_db_1
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.2  4af9653f843a
```

(value 4af9653f843a changes on each run)

i am using docker-compose 1.6.2 and docker version 1.10.3 on mac os x (so virtualbox as well)

why does it happen? how can i access db container in web container by hostname?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i just realized that i need to run

```
docker-compose up
```

at least once before i can ping it